# JDBC CommunicationsException with MySQL Database

Tags: java, tomcat, jdbc, quartz-scheduler

I'm having a little trouble with my MySQL- Connection- Pooling.
This is the case:

Different jobs are scheduled via Quartz. All jobs connect to different databases which works fine the whole day while the nightly scheduled jobs fail with a CommunicationsException...

Quartz-Jobs:

```
Job1 runs 0 0 6,10,14,18 * * ?
Job2 runs 0 30 10,18 * * ?
Job3 runs 0 0 5 * * ?
```

As you can see the last job runs at 18 taking about 1 hour to run.
The first job at 5am is the one that fails. I already tried all kinds of parameter-combinations in my resource config this is the one I am running right now:

```
<!-- Database 1 (MySQL) -->
<Resource
 auth="Container"
 driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
 maxActive="100"
 maxIdle="30"
 maxWait="10000"
 removeAbandoned="true"
 removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
 logAbandoned="true"
 type="javax.sql.DataSource"
 name="jdbc/appDbProd"
 username="****"
 password="****"
 url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/appDbProd?autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8"
 testWhileIdle="true"
 testOnBorrow="true"
 testOnReturn="true"
 validationQuery="SELECT 1"
 timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="1800000"
/>

<!-- Database 2 (MySQL) -->
<Resource
 auth="Container"
 driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
 maxActive="100"
 maxIdle="30"
 maxWait="10000"
 removeAbandoned="true"
 removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
 logAbandoned="true"
 type="javax.sql.DataSource"
 name="jdbc/prodDbCopy"
 username="****"
 password="****"
 url="jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/prodDbCopy?autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8"
 testWhileIdle="true"
 testOnBorrow="true"
 testOnReturn="true"
 validationQuery="SELECT 1"
 timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="1800000"
/>
<!-- Database 3 (MSSQL)-->
<Resource
 auth="Container"
 driverClassName="net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
 maxActive="30"
 maxIdle="30"
 maxWait="100"
 removeAbandoned="true"
 removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
 logAbandoned="true"
 name="jdbc/catalogDb"
 username="****"
 password="****"
 type="javax.sql.DataSource"
 url="jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;databaseName=catalog;useNdTLMv2=false"
 testWhileIdle="true"
 testOnBorrow="true"
 testOnReturn="true"
 validationQuery="SELECT 1"
 timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="1800000"
/>
```

For obvious reasons I changed IPs, Usernames and Passwords but they can be assumed to be correct, seeing that the application runs successfully the whole day.

The most annoying thing is:
The first job that runs first queries Database2 successfully but fails to query Database1 for some reason (CommunicationsException):

> Caused by:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException:
>   The last packet successfully received
>   from the server was 39,376,539
>   milliseconds ago.  The last packet
>   sent successfully to the server was
>   39,376,539 milliseconds ago. is longer
>   than the server configured value of
>   'wait_timeout'. You should consider
>   either expiring and/or testing
>   connection validity before use in your
>   application, increasing the server
>   configured values for client timeouts,
>   or using the Connector/J connection
>   property 'autoReconnect=true' to avoid
>   this problem.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: what version of the mysql connecter/j are you using? also what are the mysql versions that are running on db1 and db2?

Comment: Hi Justin,

Mysql connector/j version is 5.1.12
Mysql server version is 5.1.37-enterprise-gpl-advanced-log

Comment: Anything interesting in the stack trace on the exception?  Are you properly using the connection pool?

Comment: Sadly there's nothing interesting on the stack trace, except that message above. I don't know if i use it "properly", that depends on what you mean by "properly" ;)
Although this post more than 3 Month old, the problem still exists... I wonder why nobody else on the project complains about this ^_^

Comment: I'm experiencing a similar issue. I've tried everything dsiebel has tried as well, and still get these errors. Did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

As it says, enable connection validation on the connection pool.

Comment: Wow, there's a quick one ;o)
As it says, so I did ;)
As you can see in the resource configuration I already added all kinds of validation parameters. Still no luck...

Answer (score 0):

I get this error when a connection is left idle for a while. Do your jobs stop hitting the DB at some point, then run some queries?

It also happens when there's a link failure, you might want to check with your network team if the connection doesn't drop.

Comment: Yes, they do. The Last job runs at 6pm, the first one at 5am. The Problem is: this concerns only one database. As I said a Select-Query on DB2 works perfectly whil a similar query fails on DB1, both weren't in use for about the same time.
Also there's a bunch of parameters which should prevent for invalid connections to remain in the pool, right?

Answer (score 0):

I have run into a similar issue using Oracle, and JDBC. It ended up I was consuming all of the connections that were available to the database, and I wasn't relinquishing any of them and my code would just halt or timeout. Take a look at how you are handling your connections in your code.